# Scatter graph's Y axis always starting at 0

Tags: python, plotly

I'm getting a Plotly issue.

I need my scatter graph's Y axis to always start at 0. The graph object is created and returned by an auxiliary function as follows:

```
[go.Scatter(x=time_index,
            y=self.data,
            name=self.data.name
              )]
```

And then this function returns it and there is another function that actually generates the graph in a dash object, because it is a web application that I need this for.

The thing is that I need to know if there is some attribute inside the go.Scatter object that I can edit in order to always get the Y axis to start at 0.

As you can see in the image below, the Y axis starts at 10k rather than at 0.

[image]

Comment: Check this forum, something might work: https://community.plot.ly/t/make-plotly-always-show-the-origin-0-0-when-making-the-plot-in-plotly-js/15796/3

Answer (score 25):

As far as I know it's not possible to set this property in the go.Scatter object directly, but there is a layout parameter called `rangemode` wich you can set to `'tozero'`:

`fig.update_yaxes(rangemode="tozero")`

Comment: But how would I use this layout parameter in the go.Scatter object?

Comment: it cannot be set in `go.Scatter`, unfortunately, as it is a layout-level attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If it still has not been resolved - "go.Scatter()" in the Plotly could be the part of a global figure (*go.Figure()*), so you could change the layout for the parent, i.e.

```
fig = go.Figure() 
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time_index,
                         y=self.data,
                         name=self.data.name))
fig.update_layout(yaxis_range=[0, 1.1*max(self.data)])
```

*Note*: the "yaxis_range" has the following format - [<min_value>, <max_value>], so I have added extra 10% to maximum value.